# Printing a jtable with specific text before and after of it

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I studied the example code [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#printing) about printing a jtable and works fine for me. 
Now I came on an other problem. How can I define a text to be printed before and sometimes after the jtable contents? Would it be suitable to create a html header or footer and insert it like the tutorial code indicates ? Or is a better way to do it?
The text will be consists from several static lines and some with values that the user predefines before the jtable will be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I define a text to be printed before and sometimes after the jtable contents?

- these two areas are Header and Footer
- you have look at separate Tutorial about [How to Print Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html)
- more info in my [question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144775/messageformat-header-footerformat-how-to-change-font-for-jtable-printing), you have to created own Header and Footer