# How to print multiple header lines with MessageFormat using a JTable

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, messageformat

I have a table called `table` and its filled with data, I also have a `MessageFormat` header I want to use as a header to print the `JTable` this is the `MessageFormat`:

```
MessageFormat header = new  MessageFormat("Product: "
                    + task.getProductName() + "  Job: "
                    + task.getJobNumber() + "  Task: " + task.getTaskID()
                    );
```

**I want to print 3 lines in the header, one for Product, Job and Task**

the way I print this `table` is like so:

```
table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, null);
```

I can't seem to figure out how to print the header in 3 seperate lines, I tried using the `\n` to make a new line but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's gonna be long answer (code wise) because the only solution I found was to implement a custom `Printable`. Of course I didn't write the following code myself, I mostly copied the code I extracted from the jdk sources and made some adjustments.

Here we are:

This is the way you said you invoke the print method:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] { "Column 1" }, 1);

JTable table = new JTable(dtm) {
@Override
    public Printable getPrintable(PrintMode printMode, MessageFormat headerFormat, MessageFormat footerFormat) {
       return new TablePrintable(this, printMode, headerFormat, footerFormat);
    }
};
```

where `TablePrintable` is the following class (sorry for not being concise here):

```
static class TablePrintable implements Printable {

    private final JTable table;
    private final JTableHeader header;
    private final TableColumnModel colModel;
    private final int totalColWidth;
    private final JTable.PrintMode printMode;
    private final MessageFormat headerFormat;
    private final MessageFormat footerFormat;
    private int last = -1;
    private int row = 0;
    private int col = 0;
    private final Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private final Rectangle hclip = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private final Rectangle tempRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private static final int H_F_SPACE = 8;
    private static final float HEADER_FONT_SIZE = 18.0f;
    private static final float FOOTER_FONT_SIZE = 12.0f;
    private final Font headerFont;
    private final Font footerFont;

    public TablePrintable(JTable table, JTable.PrintMode printMode, MessageFormat headerFormat,
            MessageFormat footerFormat) {

        this.table = table;

        header = table.getTableHeader();
        colModel = table.getColumnModel();
        totalColWidth = colModel.getTotalColumnWidth();

        if (header != null) {
            // the header clip height can be set once since it's unchanging
            hclip.height = header.getHeight();
        }

        this.printMode = printMode;

        this.headerFormat = headerFormat;
        this.footerFormat = footerFormat;

        // derive the header and footer font from the table's font
        headerFont = table.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, HEADER_FONT_SIZE);
        footerFont = table.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, FOOTER_FONT_SIZE);
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

        // for easy access to these values
        final int imgWidth = (int) pageFormat.getImageableWidth();
        final int imgHeight = (int) pageFormat.getImageableHeight();

        if (imgWidth <= 0) {
            throw new PrinterException("Width of printable area is too small.");
        }

        // to pass the page number when formatting the header and footer
        // text
        Object[] pageNumber = new Object[] { Integer.valueOf(pageIndex + 1) };

        // fetch the formatted header text, if any
        String headerText = null;
        if (headerFormat != null) {
            headerText = headerFormat.format(pageNumber);
        }

        // fetch the formatted footer text, if any
        String footerText = null;
        if (footerFormat != null) {
            footerText = footerFormat.format(pageNumber);
        }

        // to store the bounds of the header and footer text
        Rectangle2D hRect = null;
        Rectangle2D fRect = null;

        // the amount of vertical space needed for the header and footer
        // text
        int headerTextSpace = 0;
        int footerTextSpace = 0;

        // the amount of vertical space available for printing the table
        int availableSpace = imgHeight;

        // if there's header text, find out how much space is needed for it
        // and subtract that from the available space
        if (headerText != null) {
            graphics.setFont(headerFont);
            int nbLines = headerText.split("\n").length;
            hRect = graphics.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(headerText, graphics);

            hRect = new Rectangle2D.Double(hRect.getX(), Math.abs(hRect.getY()), hRect.getWidth(),
                    hRect.getHeight() * nbLines);

            headerTextSpace = (int) Math.ceil(hRect.getHeight() * nbLines);
            availableSpace -= headerTextSpace + H_F_SPACE;
        }

        // if there's footer text, find out how much space is needed for it
        // and subtract that from the available space
        if (footerText != null) {
            graphics.setFont(footerFont);
            fRect = graphics.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(footerText, graphics);

            footerTextSpace = (int) Math.ceil(fRect.getHeight());
            availableSpace -= footerTextSpace + H_F_SPACE;
        }

        if (availableSpace <= 0) {
            throw new PrinterException("Height of printable area is too small.");
        }

        // depending on the print mode, we may need a scale factor to
        // fit the table's entire width on the page
        double sf = 1.0D;
        if (printMode == JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH && totalColWidth > imgWidth) {

            // if not, we would have thrown an acception previously
            assert imgWidth > 0;

            // it must be, according to the if-condition, since imgWidth > 0
            assert totalColWidth > 1;

            sf = (double) imgWidth / (double) totalColWidth;
        }

        // dictated by the previous two assertions
        assert sf > 0;

        // This is in a loop for two reasons:
        // First, it allows us to catch up in case we're called starting
        // with a non-zero pageIndex. Second, we know that we can be called
        // for the same page multiple times. The condition of this while
        // loop acts as a check, ensuring that we don't attempt to do the
        // calculations again when we are called subsequent times for the
        // same page.
        while (last < pageIndex) {
            // if we are finished all columns in all rows
            if (row >= table.getRowCount() && col == 0) {
                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }

            // rather than multiplying every row and column by the scale
            // factor
            // in findNextClip, just pass a width and height that have
            // already
            // been divided by it
            int scaledWidth = (int) (imgWidth / sf);
            int scaledHeight = (int) ((availableSpace - hclip.height) / sf);

            // calculate the area of the table to be printed for this page
            findNextClip(scaledWidth, scaledHeight);

            last++;
        }

        // create a copy of the graphics so we don't affect the one given to
        // us
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();

        // translate into the co-ordinate system of the pageFormat
        g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

        // to save and store the transform
        AffineTransform oldTrans;

        // if there's footer text, print it at the bottom of the imageable
        // area
        if (footerText != null) {
            oldTrans = g2d.getTransform();

            g2d.translate(0, imgHeight - footerTextSpace);

            String[] lines = footerText.split("\n");
            printText(g2d, lines, fRect, footerFont, imgWidth);

            g2d.setTransform(oldTrans);
        }

        // if there's header text, print it at the top of the imageable area
        // and then translate downwards
        if (headerText != null) {
            String[] lines = headerText.split("\n");
            printText(g2d, lines, hRect, headerFont, imgWidth);

            g2d.translate(0, headerTextSpace + H_F_SPACE);
        }

        // constrain the table output to the available space
        tempRect.x = 0;
        tempRect.y = 0;
        tempRect.width = imgWidth;
        tempRect.height = availableSpace;
        g2d.clip(tempRect);

        // if we have a scale factor, scale the graphics object to fit
        // the entire width
        if (sf != 1.0D) {
            g2d.scale(sf, sf);

            // otherwise, ensure that the current portion of the table is
            // centered horizontally
        } else {
            int diff = (imgWidth - clip.width) / 2;
            g2d.translate(diff, 0);
        }

        // store the old transform and clip for later restoration
        oldTrans = g2d.getTransform();
        Shape oldClip = g2d.getClip();

        // if there's a table header, print the current section and
        // then translate downwards
        if (header != null) {
            hclip.x = clip.x;
            hclip.width = clip.width;

            g2d.translate(-hclip.x, 0);
            g2d.clip(hclip);
            header.print(g2d);

            // restore the original transform and clip
            g2d.setTransform(oldTrans);
            g2d.setClip(oldClip);

            // translate downwards
            g2d.translate(0, hclip.height);
        }

        // print the current section of the table
        g2d.translate(-clip.x, -clip.y);
        g2d.clip(clip);
        table.print(g2d);

        // restore the original transform and clip
        g2d.setTransform(oldTrans);
        g2d.setClip(oldClip);

        // draw a box around the table
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawRect(0, 0, clip.width, hclip.height + clip.height);

        // dispose the graphics copy
        g2d.dispose();

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    private void printText(Graphics2D g2d, String[] lines, Rectangle2D rect, Font font, int imgWidth) {

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setFont(font);

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            int tx;

            // if the text is small enough to fit, center it
            if (rect.getWidth() < imgWidth) {
                tx = (int) (imgWidth / 2 - g2d.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(lines[i], g2d).getWidth() / 2);

                // otherwise, if the table is LTR, ensure the left side of
                // the text shows; the right can be clipped
            } else if (table.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight()) {
                tx = 0;

                // otherwise, ensure the right side of the text shows
            } else {
                tx = -(int) (Math.ceil(rect.getWidth()) - imgWidth);
            }

            int ty = (int) Math.ceil(Math.abs(rect.getY() + i * rect.getHeight() / lines.length));
            g2d.drawString(lines[i], tx, ty);
        }
    }

    private void findNextClip(int pw, int ph) {
        final boolean ltr = table.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight();

        // if we're ready to start a new set of rows
        if (col == 0) {
            if (ltr) {
                // adjust clip to the left of the first column
                clip.x = 0;
            } else {
                // adjust clip to the right of the first column
                clip.x = totalColWidth;
            }

            // adjust clip to the top of the next set of rows
            clip.y += clip.height;

            // adjust clip width and height to be zero
            clip.width = 0;
            clip.height = 0;

            // fit as many rows as possible, and at least one
            int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
            int rowHeight = table.getRowHeight(row);
            do {
                clip.height += rowHeight;

                if (++row >= rowCount) {
                    break;
                }

                rowHeight = table.getRowHeight(row);
            } while (clip.height + rowHeight <= ph);
        }

        // we can short-circuit for JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH since
        // we'll always fit all columns on the page
        if (printMode == JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH) {
            clip.x = 0;
            clip.width = totalColWidth;
            return;
        }

        if (ltr) {
            // adjust clip to the left of the next set of columns
            clip.x += clip.width;
        }

        // adjust clip width to be zero
        clip.width = 0;

        // fit as many columns as possible, and at least one
        int colCount = table.getColumnCount();
        int colWidth = colModel.getColumn(col).getWidth();
        do {
            clip.width += colWidth;
            if (!ltr) {
                clip.x -= colWidth;
            }

            if (++col >= colCount) {
                // reset col to 0 to indicate we're finished all columns
                col = 0;

                break;
            }

            colWidth = colModel.getColumn(col).getWidth();
        } while (clip.width + colWidth <= pw);

    }
}
```

And here is the result (I hope that's what you expect):
[image: JTable with multiple line header when printed]

Comment: It looks good, i'll try it out tomorrow at work and see if it works out.

Comment: +1 though I prefer to delegate to the table's default printable instead of c&p all

Comment: me too. I would have extend the class if I could but its visibility was default/package, so I couldn't...

Comment: none taken :) and I still agree with you, just that extend would have been better (in my opinion) since it would have led to much less coding. Delete would be the second choice (the first valid in that case) but since it's not my project I don't bother ...

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("Product: ");
builder.append(task.getProductName());
builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
builder.append("Job: ");
builder.append(task.getJobNumber());
builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
builder.append("Task: ");
builder.append(task.getTaskID();

MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat(builder.toString());
```

If this doesn't work, then you're going to have to set up your own printer job, and layout the header precisely as you want it.

Comment: Nope not talking about a JTable header but the header of the page printed, the header is separate from the actual table. I tried that and the HTML wasn't parsed.

Comment: @Epicmaster: You might want to make it clearer in your question that you're printing.

Comment: I said "I want to print 3 lines..."  I said "the way I print this table is:" the print() was used in the expression, I thought that was obvious enough, but i'll try and make it more obvious next time. But using System.getProperty("line.separator") doesn't seem to work with or without the StringBuilder, even though the builder seems to show up in the console correctly.

Comment: Then you're going to have to put together your own PrintJob.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [`getPrintable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getPrintable%28javax.swing.JTable.PrintMode,%20java.text.MessageFormat,%20java.text.MessageFormat%29) method instead without adding a header/footer text, you can then include/decorate the returned `Printable` in one where you have more control over the header, and where you can specify multi-line headers. See the javadoc of that method which mentions

> It is entirely valid for this Printable to be wrapped inside another in order to create complex reports and documents. You may even request that different pages be rendered into different sized printable areas. The implementation must be prepared to handle this (possibly by doing its layout calculations on the fly). However, providing different heights to each page will likely not work well with PrintMode.NORMAL when it has to spread columns across pages.

I have not enough experience with `Printable`s to help you further on how to actually do this

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the answer of @aymeric is correct: there's no way around a custom printable implementation. A way to do it with slightly less c&p is to have a custom implementation that

- takes over header/footer printing
- delegates to table printing itself to the default printable

The trick in that approach is to fool the delegate tablePrintable into believing that the page is smaller than it actually is, with a custom pageFormat

[more details (and code)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343475/203657)

Answer (score 0):

I've utilized two `MessageFormat` arrays as a neat solution to the problem. You'll find below a printout of the end result:

[image]

The code is outlined below:

```
try    
{
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    MessageFormat[] header = new MessageFormat[6];

    // Assign the arrays with 6 String values for the headers
    header[0] = new MessageFormat("");
    header[1] = new MessageFormat(theExamSelection);
    header[2] = new MessageFormat("");
    header[3] = new MessageFormat("Scrud 60 - Grade Returns - Random Sample");
    header[4] = new MessageFormat("");
    header[5] = new MessageFormat(theSubjectSelection+" - "+theLevelSelection+" - "+thePaperSelection);

    MessageFormat[] footer = new MessageFormat[4];

    // Assign the 4 Strings to the footer array
    footer[0] = new MessageFormat("Assistant Examiner Signature:______________  Date:___ /___ /_____ ");
    footer[1] = new MessageFormat("");
    footer[2] = new MessageFormat("");
    footer[3] = new MessageFormat("Advising  Examiner Signature:______________  Date:___ /___ /_____ ");

    //here you place the JTable to print 
    // in this case its called randomSample_gradeBreakdown_jTable
    // along with the header and footer arrays
    job.setPrintable(new PrintTableMultiLine(randomSample_gradeBreakdown_jTable, JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer ));

    job.print();

} 
catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e) 
{
    System.err.format("Cannot print %s%n", e.getMessage());

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
            "Check that your printer is working correctly","PRINT ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
            );
}
```

Comment: It's showing red line error under "PrintTableMultiLine".

Comment: It's showing red line error under "PrintTableMultiLine" The Method is Missing, Can you please paste your Compete code.