# How to print jtable and JTextfield combine?

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I want to Print JTABLE and A value from Text Field. Its like products detail and there Bill Print. 
Here is the image.

Required Print is Table + Total Amount,

But so far i got `JTable.print()` only print table. is there any way to add other values at end as total ??

Here is the code of printing jtable.

```
MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("Purchases Bill {0,number,integer}");
                    try {
                        table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, null);

                    } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e) {
                        System.err.format("Cannot print %s%n", e.getMessage());
                    }
```

[image]

Comment: Put what you want to print in a JPanel, then you can JPanel.print()

Comment: this whole stuff is in a jpanel but i just want to print one textfield not all

Comment: table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, null);
this dont work with Panel as well

Comment: You're going to have to resize the image anyway when you print to make sure it fits on the paper.

Comment: You'll have to write your own `Printable` which is capable of making space for your fields and then printing the `JTable` via it's own internal `Printable`, this is not a trivial process.  Consider using something like JasperReports or some other reporting engine, which will make your life so much simper in the long run

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc And when the image is to big to fit on a page?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598472/printable-not-working-properly/26598867#26598867) for a crude example

Answer (score 0):

Use `jtextfield1.print();` I think it will work. It will only print the specified textfield.