# Printing table in java

Tags: java, printing, jtable

I have a `JTable` in my application which I need to print. The printed page should contain only the table and some text above and below the table. So I ask what is easiest way to do this?

Do I need to create some kind of document, and then import the table in document and add the text, and then print the document?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598472/printable-not-working-properly/26598867#26598867)

Answer (score 0):

well you have to go row by row and print it out

Comment: Or just use JTable's in built printing support

Comment: or that, didn't think of it :D