# How do you add a new line in java MessageFormat ()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

Here is my code what I did

```
 MessageFormat headerFormat = new MessageFormat("Name: "+name+""+"Job No:"+job+" "+" Total-Amount: "+total);
 MessageFormat footerFormat = new MessageFormat("Details Report of "+date);
 table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH,headerFormat, footerFormat);
```

This shows output as a line but I want to show the output message like as:

> Name:Myname
>
> Job No:12
>
> Total-Amount:200

Please help me to out of this...thanks in advance

Comment: ^^ See [Kleopatra's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12105116/982149) in addition to the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

In *general* please don't use `MessageFormat` like this--if you append the Strings you do not use the advantages of a `MessageFormat`. However `print` just takes a `MessageFormat` for injecting the pageNumber.

Comment: Here is why OP is trying to do that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#print-javax.swing.JTable.PrintMode-java.text.MessageFormat-java.text.MessageFormat-