# control the size of the panel on printed page

Tags: java, swing, printing

i want to print jpanel with two tables . Two problems i faced , the first one is the Accuracy of the printed image is not very good. the second how can i control the size of the jpanel on the printed page??

here is an image of the printed page using xps viewer(the accuracy is not good)
[image]

is there away to make the printed image with this accuracy [image]like this

and this is the code:

```
     PrinterJob printjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printjob.setJobName(" TESSCO CUSTOMER CARD ");

    Printable printable = new Printable() {

            public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) {

                    if (pageNum > 0) {
                            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                    }

                    Dimension size = jPanel1.getSize();
                    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

                    jPanel1.print(bufferedImage.getGraphics());

                    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
                    g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
                    g2.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, (int) pf.getWidth(), (int) pf.getHeight(), null);

                    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
            }
    };

    Paper paper = new Paper();
    paper.setImageableArea(0, 0,700,890);
    paper.setSize(700,890);

    PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
    format.setPaper(paper);
    format.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

    printjob.setPrintable(printable, format);
    if (printjob.printDialog() == false)
            return;

    try {
            printjob.print();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
            System.out.println("NO PAGE FOUND." + ex);

    }
```

Comment: @kleopatra what do you mean by re-invent the wheel??

Comment: oops ... didn't read your first sentence ;-)

Comment: my subconcious self probably thought at something along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343475/203657 - that is implement a delegating printable which tweaks the paper setting (didn't try, but would expect to make it work for two tables)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use the pane size, you need to act as the layout manager and size the panel to fit the page.

Secondly, don't use a buffered image. This will not share the same properties as the graphics context past to you by the print engine.  Also, another print method is re-entrant, meaning that it may called a number of times for each page, creating a buffered image this way is wasteful on resources

You might like to take a look at [How to Print Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html)

**UPDATE**

You could do something like...

```
public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) {
    if (page > 0) {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)pg;

    double pageWidth = pf.getImageableWidth();
    double pageHeight = pf.getImageableHeight();

    double pageX = pf.getImageableX();
    double pageY = pf.getImageableY();

    g2d.translate(pageX, pageY);

    double tableHeight = pageHeight / 2d;

    jPanel1.setBounds(0, 0, (int)Math.floor(pageWidth), (int)Math.floor(pageHeight));
    jPanel1.printAll(g2d);

    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;

}
```

Just beware, that this could have the potential of truncating your table.  Also, you should not do this with a `Component` that is already on the screen.  You should create a new "print" component.

**UPDATE with working example**

Okay, so the concept is sound, just needed some tweaking to get it to work ;)

[image]

```
public class PrintTableTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JTable table1 = new JTable(new AbstractTableModel() {
            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int column) {
                String name = null;
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        name = "Day";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        name = "FirstName";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        name = "LastName";
                        break;
                }
                return name;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                Object value = null;
                switch (columnIndex) {
                    case 0:
                        switch (rowIndex) {
                            case 0:
                                value = "First";
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                value = "Second";
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                value = "Final";
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return value;
            }
        });
        int rowHeight = (int) Math.floor(((700f / 2f) - table1.getTableHeader().getPreferredSize().height) / 3f);
        table1.setRowHeight(rowHeight);

        PrinterJob printjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        printjob.setJobName(" TESSCO CUSTOMER CARD ");

        Printable printable;
        printable = new Printable() {
            public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) {

                if (pageNum > 0) {
                    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                }

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) pg;

                double pageWidth = pf.getImageableWidth();
                double pageHeight = pf.getImageableHeight();

                double pageX = pf.getImageableX();
                double pageY = pf.getImageableY();

                g2d.translate(pageX, pageY);

                // Each table will take half the page...
                double tableHeight = pageHeight / 2d;

                // We need to print the header as well...
                JTableHeader header = table1.getTableHeader();
                int headerHeight = header.getPreferredSize().height;

                int yOffset = 0;

                for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
                    // Set the bounds of the components
                    // The yOffset is actuall irrelevent to us, but for consitency sake
                    // we'll keep it.
                    header.setBounds(0, yOffset, (int) Math.floor(pageWidth), headerHeight);
                    table1.setBounds(0, yOffset + headerHeight, (int) Math.floor(pageWidth), (int) Math.floor(tableHeight));
                    // Force the components to update there internal layouts to match
                    // the new size. We need to do this because, technically, we're not
                    // attached to any peer, nor do we want them to be taking into account
                    // the dimensions of any parent any way :P
                    table1.doLayout();
                    header.doLayout();

                    // Translate the graphics.  Components asume a position of 0x0 when
                    // painting.  This is a side effect of the AWT/Swing painting engine
                    // (for which we are greatful), but we need to simulate the change
                    g2d.translate(0, yOffset);
                    header.printAll(g2d);
                    // Translations are relative to the last translation...
                    g2d.translate(0, headerHeight);
                    table1.printAll(g2d);
                    // Reset the last translation
                    g2d.translate(0, -(headerHeight + yOffset));

                    // Next table...
                    yOffset += table1.getHeight();
                }
                return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
            }
        };

        Paper paper = new Paper();
        paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, 700, 890);
        paper.setSize(700, 890);

        PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
        format.setPaper(paper);
        format.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

//        printjob.setPrintable(printable, format);
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(890, 700, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, 890, 700));
        try {
            printable.print(g2d, format, 0);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        g2d.dispose();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("Print.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply , i want to print two tables on the same page so i can not use print tables method. ok how can i fix the first problem programatically?????

Comment: @kleopatra ok do have any solutions??

Comment: @kleopatra, no *Athens* as in I'm an idiot with fat fat fingers

Comment: @CalmSea You're right, it didn't quite work the way either of use was expecting. The basic concept was there, but it missed the mark slightly. I've updated the answer with a **tested** working example. My example prints to a file (to save paper), but you only need to comment out the image code and unc-omment the print line.