# JAVA: Whats the best way Build a Table from a ResultSet and insert it to Ms Word

Tags: java, ms-word, resultset

i need to save my table to ms word so i can print it and see what's left using java. any help would be highly appreciated. thanks,

i tried using the Aspose.word for java but i don't seem to get it. im quite new here

[image]

Comment: [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library).  You could also print the table yourself, see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544013/how-to-print-a-jtable-object-in-the-java-application/14544898#14544898) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665089/control-the-size-of-the-panel-on-printed-page/12665357#12665357)

Comment: thank you @MadProgrammer you always save my life.