# Connecting and printing to a printer in Java

Tags: java, printing

Is there an easy way in Java to do the following?

1. Connect to a printer (will be a local printer and the only printer connected to the machine).
2. Print pages that are 2 pages in 2 different printer trays.
3. Get the current print queue count, i.e. I have 100 items to print and 34 have been currently printed, the printer queue should now read 66.

Comment: First idea is to go for something like cups4j. Not sure if basic printing api in java could handle this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887713/how-to-print-out-java-jvm-memory-use-for-debugging-purposes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some quick hints:

- print from java: see [A Basic Printing Program](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html)
- status of printing job: you might be able to get something useful by using a [PrintJobListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/event/PrintJobListener.html):

> Implementations of this listener
>   interface should be attached to a
>   DocPrintJob to monitor the status of
>   the printer job. These callback
>   methods may be invoked on the thread
>   processing the print job, or a service
>   created notification thread. In either
>   case the client should not perform
>   lengthy processing in these callbacks.

Answer (score 4):

A very good printing tutorial: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html

Also check answers to my question about printers, the Printer Job API is what are you looking for, but checking this out will also help:

[How to Send JTable data to Print Job from Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136629/how-to-send-jtable-data-to-print-job-from-java-application/6136890#6136890)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are very specific, so I'm not sure the Java printing APIs meet all your needs. You could use [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) to access your native OS's APIs directly, and that would probably get you the print-queue information.

Answer (score -3):

A simple java program to get byte Array printed

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String str = "ABCGVDVJHBDKDLNJOKBUHODVWFCVDHGSBDKS";
    byte[] byteArr = str.getBytes();

    ByteArrayInputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
    String printerID; // = give printer ID here 
    System.out.println("printerID"+printerID);
    String command = "lp -d " + printerID;

    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    OutputStream childOut = child.getOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[100000000];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        childOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    childOut.close();
    int exitVal = child.waitFor();
    InputStream childIn = child.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(childIn));
    String line;
    boolean retval;
    while ((line = is.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String finalLine = line;
    }
    childIn.close();
    if (exitVal == 0)
    {
        retval = true;
    }
```

}